# Open multiple Microsoft Edge windows from batch file

Tags: batch-file, microsoft-edge

I need to open 2 Edge windows from a batch file (not two tabs, 2 windows). I know I can launch edge using the following command:

```
start microsoft-edge:
```

But if I try it twice the second command does nothing. If I try it with URLs I get 2 tabs in the same window. e.g.

```
start microsoft-edge:http://google.com
start microsoft-edge:http://bing.com
```

Any ideas how to get 2 separate windows?

Comment: Are you only wanting to open two windows, or are you specifically trying to open two sites, giving each their own window?

Comment: Either would be fine for what I need @Sampson

Answer (score 4):

Use --new-window option:

```
start msedge http://google.com
start msedge --new-window http://bing.com
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are aware, you can trigger Microsoft Edge indirectly from the command line (or a batch file) by using the `microsoft-edge:` protocol handler. Unfortunately, this approach doesn't enable you to open up an arbitrary number of windows.

The Microsoft Edge team built a small utility to assist, and presently [hosts it on GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdgeLauncher).

```
> MicrosoftEdgeLauncher.exe http://bing.com
> MicrosoftEdgeLauncher.exe http://stackoverflow.com
```

I just tested this, and it opened two individual windows for me. There does appear to be an issue where the second window doesn't navigate to the URL; remaining open with the New Tab Page.

Comment: This didn't open multiple windows for me. Everything opened as tabs in a single window. Is there a setting in Edge that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on [Cam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66469530/15680347), the following works as of 2023 (and possibly worked back when this question was asked, as well):

```bash
start msedge --app=http://google.com
start msedge --app=http://bing.com
```

As far as I can tell, this is the simplest way of doing what the original poster is asking. You can omit `--app=` from the first URL if there's no chance the host will already be running an msedge process. But basically, that prefix guarantees you'll get a new process/window, no proxies or modules required.

Alternatively:

```
start msedge "--new-window https://google.com"
start msedge "--new-window https://bing.com"
```

The commands were tested on Windows 10 using PowerShell version 5.1.19041.2364.

Answer (score 0):

You can open as many as you like, just create batch files that call other batch files. 
Very easy to do.

Ex: batch1.cmd: 
@echo off
start microsoft-edge:http://google.com
start "path\batch2.cmd"

exit

Make sure to add "start microsoft-edge:http://bing.com" on your "batch2.cmd" file

Manny

Answer (score 0):

You can use the executable msedge_proxy.exe which is installed alongside msedge.exe. For example in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application".

Sample usage:

```
> msedge_proxy.exe --app=http://bing.com
```

If you execute that command multiple times, it pops a new window each time.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in PowerShell

start msedge "--new-window https://bing.com","--new-window https://red.com","--new-window https://yahoo.com","--new-window https://google.com","--new-window https://msn.com","--new-window https://bing.com","--new-window https://red.com","--new-window https://yahoo.com","--new-window https://google.com","--new-window https://msn.com","--new-window https://bing.com","--new-window https://red.com","--new-window https://yahoo.com","--new-window https://google.com","--new-window https://msn.com"

You can add more or change the link addresses if you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining what if anything your suggested method does differently to the other long standing answers, and why this method is preferable to the existing answers. Also consider adding formatting so it doesn't look like a block of jumbled commands that are difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
start "" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
start "" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
start "" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
```

so this will start microsoft edge 3 times

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).